# Associated table for counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4. I have the following:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have `lists_count` in `Profile` table, and I want to use it as a List counter cache. I didn't put it in User because my User model is solely for authentication. I don't want to add any non-related columns beyond authentication.

How do I do that every time a list is created, `Profile.lists_count` gets +1?

Comment: Then semantically your `Profile` class may be a closer match to what is traditionally represented by `User`. Your `User` class then becomes closer to what `LoginSession` would mean. If this interpretation is correct, why not rearrange the class names to be more representative of the underlying concerns?

Answer (score 0):

I would add an 'after_create' method in your List model:

```
 class List < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create :add_to_list_count

#There are nicer ways to do this but this will get you going
   def add_to_list_count
     self.user.profile.lists_count = self.user.profile.lists_count + 1
     self.user.profile.lists_count.save
   end
 end
```